How to interpret conditional effects for a orthogonal polynomial contrast coded categorical factor?
I understand that when estimating an interaction, the interpretation of lower order coefficients changes-- In the presence of an interaction, lower order coefficients are interpreted as conditional effects rather than main effects, where the coefficient of X1 is interpreted as the effect of X1, when X2=0.
https://www.theanalysisfactor.com/interpreting-lower-order-coefficients-when-the-model-contains-an-interaction/
In a model where X2 is a continuous variable that is Z-scored, this would be the effect of X1 when X2 is at it's mean (Z-score = 0).
In a model where X2 is a continuous variable in it's raw/unstandardized score, this would be the effect of X1 when X2 is at it's unstandardized 0.
In a model where X2 is a dummy coded categorical factor, this would be the effect of X1 at X2's dummy coded reference group.
In a model where X2 is an effects coded categorical factor, this would be the effect of X1 at X2's grand mean.
However, I get a bit stumped when it comes to a categorical factor with orthogonal polynomial contrasts. If X2 has polynomial contrasts, I am not sure what X2=0 would be for an orthogonal polynomial contrast since it doesn't have a reference group (like in effect's coding or dummy coding) and it doesn't have 0 like a continuous/numeric variable.
I know that a orthogonal polynomial contrast coded factor with four levels will have a linear effect, quadratic effect, and cubic effect, and that those effects will look different without an interaction modeled (main effects) versus with an interaction modeled (conditional effects).
What would be the interpretation of the conditional effects for an orthogonal polynomial contrast coded factor?
Here is a simulation depicting an interaction between a dummy coded categorical factor and a orthogonal polynomial contrast coded factor, so there would be conditional effects for each.
# Set seed for reproducibility
set.seed(123)

# Number of observations per combination of factors
n_per_group <- 50

# Define the 4-level factor (A) with orthogonal polynomial contrasts
A <- factor(rep(1:4, each = n_per_group))
contrasts(A) <- contr.poly(4)  # Setting orthogonal polynomial contrasts

# Define the 3-level factor (B) with dummy coding
B <- factor(rep(1:3, length.out = length(A)))
contrasts(B) <- contr.treatment(3)  # Dummy coding

# Check that A and B have the same length
length(A) == length(B)  # Should return TRUE

# Generate a continuous outcome (Y) with interaction effect
# Define coefficients for the main effects and interaction
coef_A <- c(-0.5, 0.5, -0.5)  # 3 coefficients for A (since A has 3 df with polynomial coding)
coef_B <- c(1, 2)             # 2 coefficients for B (since B has 2 df with dummy coding)

# Generate the interaction effect
# We need 3 (from A) * 2 (from B) = 6 interaction coefficients
interaction_effect <- c(0.5, -0.5, 0.3, -0.3, 0.2, -0.2)

# Create a design matrix
X <- model.matrix(~ A * B)

# Generate the outcome variable with some noise
# Make sure the length of coefficients matches the number of columns in X
Y <- X %*% c(0, coef_A, coef_B, interaction_effect) + rnorm(length(A))

# Fit a linear model
model <- lm(Y ~ A * B)

# Display the summary of the model
summary(model)

